# Use PHP to delete section of .html file

Tags: php, html, parsing

I have an HTML page I'd like to edit. I want to remove a certain section of the .html file such as.

```
<div id="gg">
......
......
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean once, or serially on request (and/or some condition)?

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using PHP's DOM library:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<html string />'); // Or $dom->loadHTMLFile('file_name.html');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[id="gg"]');
if($nodes->length)
  $nodes[0]->parentNode->removeChild($nodes[0]);

$dom->saveHTML(); // Or $dom->saveHTMLFile('file_name.html');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = file_get_contents("index.html");
$file = preg_replace('/<div id="gg">.*?<\/div>/im', '' $file);
file_put_contents($file);
```

I not tested this code.

**Attention: nested divs break html structure.**

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: What happens if there's a nested `div` in there?

Comment: I know, but in simple tasks regex is good. nested div break html. thanks for advise.

Answer (score 1):

You might have some luck using an XML (or HTML) parser. [This one](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for PHP 5 looks really easy to use, and provides a mechanism for finding a particular element by ID and then setting its contents to an empty string.